# showing the current image view on iCarousel swift4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, icarousel

I have iCarousel installed in my app, and I have the code below working that gives me the current view of the carousel. I just want to know how to make that view show on a different view controller? this is what I have so far.

```
func carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
var frontView = [carousel.itemView(at: carousel.currentItemIndex)]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what you mean for "how to make that view show on a different view controller"?

Comment: You want to share the itemView for the front tile of the carousel to another view controller? Why? Are you saying that you want the other view controller's view to update to show the front carousel tile as the carousel scrolls? That's not how UIViews work. A UIView lives in one and only one view hierarchy. You could take a snapshot of the carousel tile and pass that to another view controller if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: well I have the carousel for a nice way to have a 'background picker' when the user stops scrolling, I want the front most image in the carousel to be shown on a different view controller.

Comment: So you know how apps have different screens? I am new to programming, I am probably just using the wrong vocabulary, I want the current viewed item in the carousel to be displayed on a different screen.